# Multiple domains

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

I got 6 domains : `company.ca` and `company.com` (because both where free, but we are a canadian company but can do business with the rest of the world).

Then, we sell sportwear because of the company name is totally unknown to the world. Our product is we have bought product specific domain : `chandails.ca` and `t-shirt.ca` as well as `shorts.ca` and `shorts.com`.

So those 6 domains are mine. Now what is the best way to do? Now all are 301 redirect to the main company name (`.com`) or make micro-site, super simple one page optimized for just shirt and one for shorts, then tell people to know more, go to the *main* site.

Because now, I cannot really find the benefit of the *search word in domain name* edge if never somebody see something in that domain...

I got confused and don't find strait answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is to 301 all the "other" domains to the "main" domain, you might as well just sell those domains. If the domain's not being indexed by Google, it's virtually worthless to you.

You could use the subdomains for microsites and highly targeted landing pages. But if your just going to be sending everybody to your "main" domain anyway, it'd probably be best to put the content up there, to build up the "main" sites' trust, authority, etc.